# Manipulate the order of attribute in configurable product: Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have 2 attributes, Capacity and Quantity and i need to custom order those attributes in my configurable product, currentily is showing Capacity before Quantity, but i want the reverse, i want to show Quantity before Capacity, like the following example:

The attributes is Capacity and Quantity, and is like this

```
-Capacity
  -4GB
  -8GB
-Quantity
  -50
```

but i need to show this way

```
-Quantity
  50
-Capacity
  - 4GB
  - 8GB
```

How can i order this?

Answer (score 0):

Witch version of Magento have you?
In version CE 1.9 you can drag attribute : [image]